# How to open multiple browser windows on request? (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, post

So I have a form on `PHP/HTML` page. User submitss it to that same `PHP/HTML` page. So now PHP page I will have `$_POST` data. I want to when page is refreshed opnt some popUp browser windows which url's will be relative to users `POST` request. like `www.example.com/bal-bla-bla.php? id=$_POST['StreamId']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

echo '<script>window.open ("'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'myplayer.php?stream_id='.$_POST['StreamId'].'","myplayer");</script>';

}
```

edited:

you can always display a message before open the window that advice the user to accept this new window!

```
var flag = confirm(" This window is not an ADV! ;-) ");
if (flag)
window.open("'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'","myplayer");
```

Answer (score 6):

Include some `<script>` elements with `window.open` calls in them in the response … then watch as every popup blocker in the world blocks them.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this client side in javascript.

You could use window.open() in a document.onload event handler.

However, chances are if the user has a pop-up blocker this will be blocked.