# Open a popup window

Tags: php

Can i open a new window after execution of some code(ie at some point of time before completion i need to open a new window in zend.Can i do this?

Also how can i check the size of a remote file.

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: As for *how can i check the size of a remote file*, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729333/how-to-open-multiple-browser-windows-on-request-php

Comment: Two separate questions should be asked separately.

Comment: Hi,

Thanking you all for your replies...Well sorry for the confusion.

I thought what my need is, i will shoot that directly.It went wrong..right!!

My question was i have some script to download a zip file on a button click.Authentication,Verification leave all that.

Plain and simple, on a button click i need to download a file and after completion i need to open a new window and execute some code there..
Hope this makes sense...

I think what Vinothbabu said will work for me..n i m going to test and will post the reply soon.

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is incomplete, but let me try to give you the possible best answer. You have some PHP code written and there is some sort of verification or authentication going on. In the Middle of the process you need to openup a popup to check something.

```
        <?php
        print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        print "window.open='http://www.examples.com/page.html','new_window1',
        'status=1,scrollbars=1,
        resizable=0,menu=no,width=320,height=220'";
        print "</script>";
        ?>
```

Comment: This assumes he is running the PHP code in the View template and that the browser is not running a PopUp Blocker.

Comment: I am just assuming things and giving him a reply, as i am yet to fully construe on what is his actual requirement.